# Getting a value after promise resolved

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm trying to understand Promises as best as I can.

I was wondering if there's a way of returning the data after the promise had been resolved without chaining as much as I have

Basically i was trying to push a new location into the locs array.

loc.service.js :

```
export const locService = {
  getLocs,
};

const locs = [
  { name: 'Greatplace', lat: 32.047104, lng: 34.832384 },
  { name: 'Neveragain', lat: 32.047201, lng: 34.832581 },
];

function getLocs() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(locs);
    }, 100);
  });
}
```

map.service.js :

```
      const place = prompt('Enter place name');
      if (!place) {
        alert('Please enter a valid input');
      } else {
        locService.getLocs().then(locService.setLoc(place, event.latLng));
        locService.getLocs().then((locs) => {
          storageService.save(PLACE_KEY, locs);
```

thanks a bunch

Comment: Why are you using a promise with an entirely synchronous operation for `getLocs()`?  That is just complicating things.  In addition, you must pass a function reference to `.then()` and `locService.setLoc(...)` is NOT a function reference.  That is executing that function immediately and passing some return value to `.then()`, so it will not wait for the previous promise to finish before executing.  There is little here that is correct.  But, it looks like mostly make-up code, not real code so we can't really advise more specifically on how to solve the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. check `async/await` syntax.

[MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

---

using `async/await` instead of the `.then` chain.

```
      const place = prompt('Enter place name');
      if (!place) {
        alert('Please enter a valid input');
      } else {

       const locs = await locService.getLocs()
       storageService.save(PLACE_KEY, locs);
```

don't forget to add `async` on your wrapping function. or add another `async` function if you don't want to change how it behave.

```
 funcName = async ()=>{
// the code
}
```

Comment: @Kinglish added code. thank you for the input.